# How to find if there is youtube embed code in the text

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to search if there is youtube embed code in the text. I am using wordpress and want to find youtube embed code in post content. Do any body can provide me php regular expression to find if there is youtube embed code found in the text or not. thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow can help you if you have a particular problem with your code. But it is not the place to find people who makes the work for you. Please try the regular expression yourself. If you have problems come back, paste your code and ask a specific quetion.

Comment: @Junaid Rehman see my answer below.

Comment: ok Heri - I am trying with regular expression myself and ask question if not succeed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by adding filter to `the_content`.

**Note: It will only works when `the_content` used in template to render.**

put below code in `functions.php` and modify `if` condition as per your need.

```
function find_youtube_wp_content( $content ) {
        $regex = '~(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)/(?:watch\?v=)?([^\s]+)~';
        preg_match( $regex, $content, $match );
        if ( ! empty( $match ) && isset( $match[0] ) ) {
            echo $match[0];
        } else {

        }
    }

add_filter( 'the_content', 'find_youtube_wp_content' );
```

Comment: I mean I want to search for embed iframe code of youtube

Answer (score 0):

**I use this code and it works**

```
$regex = '/https?:\/\/\)?(?:www.)?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)\/embed\//';
        preg_match( $regex, $post->post_content, $match );
        if ( ! empty( $match ) && isset( $match[0] ) ) {
            echo $match[0];
        } else {
        }
```